# Authorship of Summarized Sefer Hamitzvos

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam

Are there any sources that claim that Rambam didnt author the summarized sefer hamitzvos (מנין מצות הקצר)?

Comment: Why might you think there would be such sources?

Comment: @DoubleAA I seem to remember seeing in the name of Maggid mishne in Eiruvin that they were written by him. I thought maybe he was coming to contradict someone.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to prove a negative, but I haven't seen any. The list comes from the Rambam starting each section of Mishnah Torah with a list of the included commandments. The commentators seem to take for granted that he wrote them and ask/answer questions on them the same way they do the rest of Mishnah Torah. See the Frankel edition of Rambam for examples.

Comment: "The list comes from the Rambam starting each section of Mishnah Torah with a list of the included commandments" I don't think that's true. "See the Frankel edition of Rambam for examples" what do you see in that edition more than any other edition? Or you mean their index in the back?

Comment: Yes, I mean the  index.

Comment: How can you think that is not true? It is in every edition of Rambam.

Comment: I'm bothered by the words "comes from". I don't think this list comes from there...if anything that list comes from here...and you'll notice there are sometimes differences between them so I don't think one comes from the other